# Can file write mode affect HMAC of text written into file?

Tags: file, lua, hmac, sha512

in an application we have a file with data, which we want to "protect" from tampering. By "protect" I mean - make it hard for a user to just edit the text file.

Data is stored in JSON format. Before writing to the file, we create JSON string and calculate HMAC. Then both of the information are written to a file. When file is read, we again generate the HMAC of the data and compare it to the stored hash.

It sounds like something trivial and something that should not cause any issues, however we are getting a lot of reports that this check fails. We get them also from our testers, who definitely didn't tamper the file.

I'm wondering if it's possible that reading/writing file could affect the process. Due to some legacy code, the file is read and written in binary mode. I'm wondering if this could affect the process? I'm not going to "let's change it and see what happens" before I have a confirmation that this could be the case.

The file is read and stored on the same system all the time, it's not transferred anywhere.

All of the operations are performed using Lua, if that makes any difference.

Thank you
Krystian

Comment: May be read mode (`r` vs `rb`)?

Comment: well... that's the thing. Before I make the change, I would like to know if it's possible or not. Making a change for the sake of making a change doesn't make sense for this application. Update cost is high, and this error is very very rare.

Comment: It possible. But better post code that generate/read/write file. I see no problem with it. You read same data which you write.